# PHP Dec to 256 ASCII char and keep the Dec value on copy

Tags: php, encryption, ascii

Need help, I have a string that goes to an encryption that returning an array of a set dec values like :

`[0, 1, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 100]`

To make it seem like a non readable I want to convert it to char with `chr()` func. The problem comes when it converting to an invisible char

`i £nEi5uNtVsd-vo`

the blank one can be space, tab, or anything. the  can be anything too when I copy it. It doesn't keep the right dec value like when it returning from the encryption. Can php show all the 256 ascii char and still keep the dec value of every char that has been converted?

Edit:
real case I have this

`[105, 26, 32, 163, 110, 69, 105, 53, 117, 78, 116, 86, 115, 6, 100, 45, 118, 12, 0, 111]`

unfortunately char with `dec 26` doesn't show properly here, in any of converter out there it shown as `?`

Comment: Apply a binary-to-text encoding like Base64 or hex for the representation of binary data as string.

Comment: Can you provide PHP code demonstrating the values you have? "decimal" is not a type in PHP, it's just one of multiple ways to display a number (actually the default). That said,  not every number maps to a readable character, so this isn't trivial. What output do you expect for your example input?

Comment: @Topaco so it's not possible to show all 256 ascii char with the char that is not printable? Base64 could be solving my problem. @UlrichEckhardt lets i make it more clear. I dont need type specific to decimal, I just need convert a string to a decimal-like value with type string surely. I expecting if I had `9` that would be a tab value in ascii and can not be shown so it will be only a blank space. When I copy it in the input, it will act like a regular space (same blank space) the dec value will not be the same as `9`

Answer (score 1):

No.

The fact that not every integer value from 0 to 256 has a printable representation is nothing to do with the language. This is what people refer to as a "binary string", "byte array", etc.

Binary strings should not be presented as though they are text, and they *certainly* should not be copy/pasted because, as you've experienced, the non-printable portions tend not to survive, not to mention the high likelihood of encoding mismatch issues for ordinal values above 127, aka "non-ASCII" or "non-7bit-safe".

If you want to represent these values as text for whatever reason you will need to apply a string-safe encoding scheme as Topaco has suggested. Eg:

```php
$in_arr = [0, 1, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 100];
$str = implode('', array_map('chr', $in_arr));

var_dump(
    bin2hex($str),
    base64_encode($str)
);
```

Output:

```
string(22) "000116212c37424d586364"
string(16) "AAEWISw3Qk1YY2Q="
```

Comment: thank you for answering, base64 sounds great for now. So there is no way to know what is the different between `tab` and `space` because it act same as blank in the output or two different symbols that shown as `?` will be just a regular question mark character?

Comment: If you want to visually review the data, then hex is usually the best option since every byte of input is represented as exactly two bytes of output. There are also utilities like hexdump that will show you the hex and plain output side-by-side for easier debugging.